# My application with RedLaser SDK

Tags: iphone, barcode

I develop my application with Evaluation RedLaser SDK .
Can I submit it into app store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Technically yes*, however they don't recommend doing it (**as in DON'T DO IT**) with the evaluation sdk because it's limited to only 25 scans per device. See [here](http://redlaser.com/frequently-asked-questions.php) for more info

Comment: what that 25 scans per device mean?

Comment: what that 25 scans per device mean? I guess per device scan only 25 times?

Comment: Uh… it means what it says.  each device that you use can only scan 25 items.

Comment: items are things that have barcodes on them, so like QR codes, items you'll find in a store, etc.